# Pandas Dataframe: Count unique words in a column and return count in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a dataframe which has the following columns

1. df['Album'] (contains album names of artistX )
2. df['Tracks'] (contains Tracks in the albums of artistX)
3. df['Lyrics'] (contains Lyrics of the tracks )

I am trying to count the number of words in df['Lyrics'] and return a new column called df['wordcount'] as well count the number of unique words in df['Lyrics'] and return a new column called df['uniquewordcount'].

I have been able to get df['wordcount'] by counting every string in df['lyrics'] minus white space.

`totalscore = df.Lyrics.str.count('[^\s]') #count every word in a track
df['wordcount'] = totalscore
df`

I have been able to count unique words in df['Lyrics']

```
import collections
from collections import Counter

results = Counter()
count_unique = df.Lyrics.str.lower().str.split().apply(results.update)
unique_counts = sum((results).values())
df['uniquewordcount'] = unique_counts
```

And that gives me the count of all the unique words in df['Lyrics'], which is what the code is meant to do, but I want the unique words in the lyrics of each track, My python isn't great currently so the solution might be obvious to everyone but not me. I would love someone to point me in the right direction on how to get the count of the unique words for each track.

expected output:

```
Album    Tracks    Lyrics                      wordcount  uniquewordcount
 A         Ball   Ball is life and Ball is key       7           5
           Pass   Pass me the hookah Pass me the     7           4
```

what I got:

```
Album    Tracks    Lyrics                    wordcount  uniquewordcount
  A     Ball   Ball is life and Ball is key       7           9
        Pass   Pass me the hookah Pass me the     7           9
```

Comment: `results` should contain all the unique words that you need. I do not understand what your actual question is. Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: How about share some data and expected output?

Comment: Thanks for your response. results returns the unique words and their counts, what I want is the count of each unique word in a track

Comment: Why not using nltk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one alternative solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Lyrics': ['This is some life some collection of words',
                              'Lyrics abound lyrics here there eveywhere',
                              'Come fly come fly away']})

# Split list into new series
lyrics = df['Lyrics'].str.lower().str.split()

# Get amount of unique words
df['LyricsCounter'] = lyrics.apply(set).apply(len)

# Get amount of words
df['LyricsWords'] = lyrics.apply(len)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
                                       Lyrics  LyricsCounter  LyricsWords
0  This is some life some collection of words              7            8
1   Lyrics abound lyrics here there eveywhere              5            6
2                      Come fly come fly away              3            5
```

Comment: Upvoting this solution as its a more direct way to reach OP's goal.

Answer (score 2):

Using just the standard library, you can indeed use `collections.Counter`. However, `ntlk` is advisable since there are many edge cases that may interest you, e.g. dealing with punctuation, plurals, etc.

Here's a step-by-step guide for `Counter`. Note we go further here than required, since we are also calculating the *counts of each word*. This data held in `Counter` dictionaries is discarded when we drop `df['LyricsCounter']`.

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'Lyrics': ['This is some life some collection of words',
                              'Lyrics abound lyrics here there eveywhere',
                              'Come fly come fly away']})

# convert to lowercase, split to list
df['LyricsList'] = df['Lyrics'].str.lower().str.split()

# for each set of lyrics, create a Counter dictionary
df['LyricsCounter'] = df['LyricsList'].apply(Counter)

# calculate length of list
df['LyricsWords'] = df['LyricsList'].apply(len)

# calculate number of Counter items for each set of lyrics
df['LyricsUniqueWords'] = df['LyricsCounter'].apply(len)

res = df.drop(['LyricsList', 'LyricsCounter'], axis=1)

print(res)

                                       Lyrics  LyricsWords  LyricsUniqueWords
0  This is some life some collection of words            8                  7
1   Lyrics abound lyrics here there eveywhere            6                  5
2                      Come fly come fly away            5                  3
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: I see various errors with this. It would not account for: `.,!`. I would probably use NLTK for something like this though :)

Comment: @AntonvBR for what I am trying to do I had preprocessed my text and removed all special characters and punctuations, so they actually don't exist in my text. Thanks a lot for your response I am just getting into NLTK and I actually used it in finding the most used words by artistX

Comment: @Sammie Ok in that case I upvote the answer. However... I think we can do it slightly "better" (which for me is more readable) without creating the "extra" columns to drop. If you like it you can upvote me. But no need to change the answer mark.